# Californian red semi-sweet wine similar to Kindzmarauli?

Tags: red-wine

I'm in search of wine which will taste similar to Georgian red semi-sweet [Kindzmarauli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saperavi#Kindzmarauli)

Can you give some advice for California citizen?

Comment: Does it have to be from California or just available in California?

Comment: Available in California.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Kindzmarauli](https://www.bluedanubewine.com/winery/kindzmarauli/) is a region in Georgia that is well known for their wines. There is also seems to be some confusion about if it's a style of wine or not. Wikipedia claims that it's a sweetish red wine made from Saperavi grapes and other sources say it's just the appellation and several grapes can be used. [Saperavi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saperavi) is a [teinturier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teinturier) grape which means it has both red skin and flesh. Most red grapes only have red skin and clear flesh. They can be very powerfully colored and are many times used to color wines that need a little help in the color department. A well known teinturier in California is [Alicante Bouschet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alicante_Bouschet) which at one time was one of the most grown grapes in California. I suspect if you could track down a off dry California Alicante Bouschet it would have a similar flavor profile. There are Saperavi grapes in California, but I don't know a winery using them.

Or you can just buy the real thing from Georgia at your [Total Wine](https://www.totalwine.com/wine/red-wine/saperavi/teliani-valley-kindzmarauli/p/38446750?s=505) store in California.

Comment: Great and descriptive answer. (The Kindzmarauli I've tasted was also sweet -like Wiki says- full body and a deep red. If memory serves correct, it resembled a Port.)